# Why is there a negative NaN in python Decimal type

Tags: python-3.x, decimal, nan

Just out of curiosity, why is there a negative NaN in Decimal type?

```
>>> Decimal('-nan')
Decimal('-NaN')
>>> float('-nan')
nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a signed NaN in floating point too. In IEEE754 (which is what *most* python interpreters use), the format consists of three fields, a sign bit, an exponent, and a fraction.

The NaN is represented by 1 bits in the exponent and a fraction component that must be non-zero.

The sign bit is not specified. That allows for the possibility of a *signed* NaN, although given that all NaN compares false for equality (including itself), the distinction is artificial.

The `Decimal` type follows the same conventions: the sign bit is not set by its NaN representation so emitting the possibility of a signed NaN.